# React on Rails Gem - Foreman Thor Conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, thor, react-on-rails

I've been trying to implement the [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/) gem using the tutorial found [here](https://youtu.be/_bjScw60FBk).

Difference being I'm using ruby 2.3.3, node 7.2.0, and ran the setup with redux (`rails generate react_on_rails:install --redux`)

However now when I try to run foreman `foreman run -f Procfile.dev` I get the following error:

```
/Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.19.3/lib/thor/base.rb:534:in `thor_reserved_word?': "run" is a Thor reserved word and cannot be defined as command (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-0.19.3/lib/thor/base.rb:597:in `method_added'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/foreman-0.82.0/lib/foreman/cli.rb:80:in `<class:CLI>'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/foreman-0.82.0/lib/foreman/cli.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/foreman-0.82.0/bin/foreman:5:in `require'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/foreman-0.82.0/bin/foreman:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/foreman:22:in `load'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/foreman:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/ryanking/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why this is happening & how I could fix it?

---

Procfile.dev contains:

```
web: rails s -p 3000
client: sh -c 'rm app/assets/webpack/* || true && cd client && npm run build:development'
```

Which I can run fine from the command line but not with foreman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/653)

> After upgrading to thor-0.19.2 from thor-0.19.1

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference - still generates the same response

Comment: Which the command generate response? Do you understand the difference between `run` and `start` arguments? What's error you have?

Comment: Same error as above. For both run and start commands. 
`bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev` & `bundle exec foreman run -f Procfile.dev`

Comment: @RyanKing that's strange because it is works for me as expected, I run my foreman with `bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev`.

Comment: try to run `Procfile.dev` with only one command `web: bundle exec rails server`

Comment: Strange - I still get the same error with only `web: bundle exec rails server` in `Procfile.dev`